No bias Correction for Bert
im trying to take a Kfold Test on my BertModel.
First i trained my model for reveling PII and i saved the state of it in 2 file : optimazer.pt and bert_model.pt
Here's how
 def save_model(self, model_path, optimizer_path):         
    torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), model_path)         
    torch.save(self.optim.state_dict(), optimizer_path)  

But now im trying to take a Kfold test(with not a large dataset, just seeing if it makes trough this) and it's making this  error .
File "/home/gsafractal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py", line 651, in step
    if group["correct_bias"]:  # No bias correction for Bert

Here's the code
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification, AdamW
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Classe per il caricamento del dataset dal CSV
class CSVDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, text_column, label_column):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.texts = self.df[text_column].tolist()
        self.labels = self.df[label_column].tolist()
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        encoded = self.tokenizer(self.texts[idx], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors='pt')
        label = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return encoded['input_ids'].squeeze(), encoded['attention_mask'].squeeze(), label

# Classe per il caricamento del modello BERT e dei file pt
class BertModelLoader:
    def __init__(self, model_path, optimizer_path=None, num_labels=2):
        self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=num_labels)
        self.model.to(self.device)
        
        # Initialize optimizer
        self.optimizer = AdamW(self.model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, correct_bias=True)

        # Load model and optimizer states if paths are provided
        if model_path:
            self.load_model(model_path, optimizer_path)

    def load_model(self, model_path, optimizer_path=None):
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, map_location=self.device))
        self.model.to(self.device)  # Move model to the correct device
        
        # Initialize optimizer with default parameters if needed
        self.optimizer = AdamW(self.model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, correct_bias=True)
        
        if optimizer_path:
            try:
                optimizer_state_dict = torch.load(optimizer_path, map_location=self.device)
                self.optimizer.load_state_dict(optimizer_state_dict)
                print('Optimizer loaded successfully.')
            except KeyError as e:
                print(f"Key error while loading optimizer state: {e}")
                print("Reinitializing optimizer.")
                self.optimizer = AdamW(self.model.parameters(), lr=2e-5, correct_bias=True)
    
    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def get_optimizer(self):
        return self.optimizer

    def get_device(self):
        return self.device

# Classe per il K-Fold Cross Validation
class KFoldTrainer:
    def __init__(self, model, optimizer, device, epochs=3, batch_size=8):
        self.model = model
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.device = device
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def train_fold(self, train_loader, fold, epoch):
        self.model.train()
        total_loss = 0
        for batch_idx, (input_ids, attention_mask, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            input_ids, attention_mask, labels = input_ids.to(self.device), attention_mask.to(self.device), labels.to(self.device)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = self.model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
            loss = outputs.loss
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()
            total_loss += loss.item()

            if batch_idx % 10 == 0:
                print(f'Fold {fold + 1}, Epoch {epoch + 1}, Batch {batch_idx}, Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
        
        return total_loss / len(train_loader)

    def evaluate_fold(self, val_loader, fold):
        self.model.eval()
        preds, true_labels = [], []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for input_ids, attention_mask, labels in val_loader:
                input_ids, attention_mask, labels = input_ids.to(self.device), attention_mask.to(self.device), labels.to(self.device)
                outputs = self.model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
                logits = outputs.logits
                preds.append(torch.argmax(logits, dim=1).cpu().numpy())
                true_labels.append(labels.cpu().numpy())

        preds = np.concatenate(preds)
        true_labels = np.concatenate(true_labels)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(true_labels, preds)
        print(f'Fold {fold + 1}, Validation Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')
        return accuracy

    def run_kfold(self, dataset, k_folds=5):
        kfold = KFold(n_splits=k_folds, shuffle=True)
        accuracies = []

        for fold, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(kfold.split(dataset)):
            print(f'\n--- Fold {fold + 1}/{k_folds} ---')

            train_subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_idx)
            val_subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, val_idx)
            
            train_loader = DataLoader(train_subset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)
            val_loader = DataLoader(val_subset, batch_size=self.batch_size)

            # Training del modello
            for epoch in range(self.epochs):
                print(f'Inizio Epoch {epoch + 1}/{self.epochs} per il Fold {fold + 1}...')
                train_loss = self.train_fold(train_loader, fold, epoch)
                print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{self.epochs} completato, Loss: {train_loss:.4f}')

            # Valutazione del modello
            print(f'Eseguendo la valutazione per il Fold {fold + 1}...')
            accuracy = self.evaluate_fold(val_loader, fold)
            accuracies.append(accuracy)

        print(f'\nK-Fold Cross Validation accuracies: {accuracies}')
        print(f'Mean Accuracy: {np.mean(accuracies):.4f}')




# 1. Caricamento del dataset
dataset = CSVDataset(csv_file, text_column, label_column)

# 2. Caricamento del modello BERT e dell'ottimizzatore
model_loader = BertModelLoader(model_path, optimizer_path)
model = model_loader.get_model()
optimizer = model_loader.get_optimizer()
device = model_loader.get_device()

# 3. K-Fold Cross Validation
trainer = KFoldTrainer(model, optimizer, device, epochs=3, batch_size=8)
trainer.run_kfold(dataset, k_folds=3)

Can anyone help me? I think that the problem is on the 'saving files' optimazer.pt and bert_model.pt but i cant find anything online.
For people asking , the codes makes troguht the part of loading the file, so the problem is not there.
I tried to check inside the optimazer.pt file and i didnt find the correct_bias i was looking for.
Maybe is that the problem but im not sure.
Another things i tried is trying to fine tuning again my model and then rerun the kfold test.
I also try to run the test with the only file that came with that
torch.save(model_trainer, 'path')

but nothing

thy for providing the code u are running but we can test it on our machines since we don't have the training data or a simple example. So it would be beneficial if you could provide a small sample
